# Fast parsing simple large files

Tags: ruby, parsing, text-files

I perform simple parsing of large files.
I'm trying to select blocks from a large text file and write these blocks into a new text file. My current method works very slowly because parsing files include more 3 million strings.
For example:
file for parsing:

```
1test
1111
2222
3333
4444
1test
5555
6666
2test
5555
4444
3test
0000
4test
9999
0000
5test
3333
3333
8test
2222
9test
6666
11test
1111
```

I want et next data in new file:

```
1test
1111
2222
3333
4444
1test
5555
6666
2test
5555
4444
3test
0000
4test
9999
0000
5test
3333
3333
```

In shortly, I'm trying to select specific blocks from the source file.

My Code:

```
arr = []

data = File.read("/path/to/file")

blocks = ['1test','2test','3test','4test','5test']
blocks.each do |block|

want = data.match(/#{block}(.*)#{block}/m)[0]
want.each_line do |line|
  arr << line
  File.open("/path/to/result/file", 'w') { |file| file.write("#{res.join}") }
end

end
```

I think that my problem is that I read the data "want" many times. 
Is there a way to write to the result file in one pass of the "want" data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def save_blocks(fname_in, fname_out, *blocks)
  sblocks = blocks.to_set
  save = false
  File.open(fname_out, 'w') do |f|
    File.foreach(fname_in) do |line|
      lc = line.chomp
      save = sblocks.include?(lc) if lc =~ /\A\d+test\z/
      f.write(line) if save
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

Let's first create a test file where `str` is the example string given in the question.

```
FNameIn  = "test.in"
FNameOut = "test.out"
File.write(FNameIn, str)
  #=> 135
```

We can check that.

```
puts File.read(FNameIn)
1test
1111
2222
...
3test
0000
4test
...
11test
1111
```

Now we execute the method.

```
save_blocks(FNameIn, FNameOut, "1test", "3test", "5test")
```

We can confirm the output file was written correctly.

```
puts File.read(FNameOut)
1test
1111
2222
3333
4444
1test
5555
6666
3test
0000
5test
3333
3333
```

I converted `blocks` to a set merely to speed the operation of `include?`. There is no need to explicitly close either file, as they are closed when their respective blocks return.